# Weird exception with Intermec PR3 android drivers

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer, intermec

I am integrating an android app with Intermec PR3 printer.
This is what what I done in order to implement the same.

1. Download the drivers/ LinePrinter.jar from https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Where-to-download-Intermec-printing-SDK-for-Android
2. Implement the code as per the samples provided. Add LinePrinter.jar to the classpath.

Install LinePrinterService app from honeywell onto the android prone.

Post that, I try to initialize LinePrinter with below code -

```
LinePrinter  lp = new LinePrinter(profiles.getAbsolutePath(), "PR3",
                "bt://68:0A:D2:4F:5X:K5", exSettings);
```

However, I get a weird exception -

```
W/System.err: com.intermec.print.lp.LinePrinterException: java.lang.Class<com.intermec.print.android.AndroidPrinter> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.intermec.print.Printer>
W/System.err:     at com.intermec.print.lp.LinePrinter.<init>(Unknown Source:18)
W/System.err:     at com.example.print_honeywell.FirstFragment.doPrint(FirstFragment.java:109)
W/System.err:     at com.example.print_honeywell.FirstFragment.access$000(FirstFragment.java:38)
W/System.err:     at com.example.print_honeywell.FirstFragment$1.onClick(FirstFragment.java:58)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7520)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
```

Does anyone know what this exception mean? I am totally stuck on this.. Moreover somehow I cannot debug in android studio either, because driver sources are not available.
Is it something to do with java version?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem and also downloaded the printer SDK from [Where-to-download-Intermec-printing-SDK-for-Android link](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Where-to-download-Intermec-printing-SDK-for-Android). But nothing works and the same error as you. I found another SDK jar file for the printer in the project I work on it.

So the solution that works for me:

- I used the SDK I found in the project I work on it (I uploaded it to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A_OWkcNUMIRCOsaDNLG5GSXCFB00ivB5?usp=sharing) for you)
- install LinePrintService-release.apk (I uploaded it also into the same folder in google drive)

I hope that will work for you. Don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I follow your solution but encounter LinePrinterException: Print Service is not available exception when trying to call lp = new LinePrinter(
                  profiles.getAbsolutePath(),
                  sPrinterID,
                  sPrinterURI,
                  exSettings);